# Auto convert Xls to CSV

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, export-to-csv

I am using the following VBS script found on stackoverflow to convert xls to csv.  It works fine.   I want to run it with the batch file at the bottom.   I don't know how to achieve what I want.  The batch file gives the csv file the same name as the xls file.  Because the xls file has two worksheets in it I need to produce two csv's for each xls file

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(2), 6

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Here's the batch file

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.xlsx /b') DO ExcelToCSV.vbs "%%i" "%%i.csv"
```

I need to pass in 2 output .csv file names   one should be nnnnn_1.csv the other should be nnnnn_2.csv to account for the 2 worksheets in the xls files.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks Scott, I couldn't make that happen

Answer (score 2):

If you change the `VBS` script to this it should work:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))

oBook.Worksheets(1).Copy
Dim oBookNew1     
Set oBookNew1 = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
oBookNew1.SaveAs Replace(WScript.Arguments.Item(1),".csv","_1.csv"), 6
oBookNew1.Close False

oBook.Worksheets(2).Copy
Dim oBookNew1     
Set oBookNew1 = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
oBookNew2.SaveAs Replace(WScript.Arguments.Item(1),".csv","_2.csv"), 6
oBookNew2.Close False

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina - The Copy method is very much a function. What is the error you get? It may need a bit more argument with `VBS` though.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - see my edit. I think I know why the line didn't work.

Comment: oExcel.ActiveWorkbook is not available in VBScript

Comment: I am sorry I was wrong.  It's ActiveWorksheet that isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to Scott's answer above, I would probably change the script to work this way, since this change will just work for all sheets in a given workbook and output each to a `.csv` file without worrying if there are 1, 2 or 10 sheets.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook 
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Dim oNewBook
shIndex = 1 ' start with 1
For shIndex = 1 To oBook.Worksheets.Count     
    oBook.Worksheets(shIndex).Copy
    Set oNewBook = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    oNewBook.SaveAs Replace(WScript.Arguments.Item(1),".csv","_" & shIndex & ".csv"), 6
    oNewBook.Close False
Next
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: The Copy method is not a function. This line fails `Set oBookNew1 = oBook.Worksheets(1).Copy`

Comment: You're right - fixed it now. (though the line you mention wasn't actually in my code anyway, I used `shIndex` rather than 1) :)

Comment: oExcel.ActiveWorkbook is not available in VBScript

Comment: Yes it is... `ActiveWorkbook` is available via the `application` object, which is what `oExcel` was set to.  I tried it in VBSEdit and the intellisense happily agreed with me

Comment: I apologize. I was wrong.  It's ActiveWorksheet that isn't available.

Comment: On a slightly related note, although `ActiveWorksheet` isn't available, you CAN use the identical `ActiveSheet` from any workbook level object.

Comment: That makes since.  I assume the `Application.Cell(1,1)` is invalid also.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This script will save every worksheet in the workbook as `[cvs base name] - [worksheet name].csv`.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    WScript.Quit
End If


Dim BaseName, oExcel, oBook, xlWorksheet, i

BaseName = Replace( WScript.Arguments.Item(0), ".cvs", "")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))

For Each xlWorksheet In oBook.Worksheets
    xlWorksheet.Copy
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs BaseName & " - " & xlWorksheet.Name & ".csv"
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an alternative solution in Python that exports the present excel sheets of a workbook in CVS format.

You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/julianthome/2d8546e7bed869079ab0f409ae0faa87)

Best,
  Julian